# How to add properties of objects returned in JSON into a template

Tags: jquery, django

I want to print the only `state_name` value in the HTML template. How can I print those values in the template using jQuery?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://localhost:8000/country_state/",
  data: {
    "country": selectedCountry
  },
  success: function(response) {
    alert('success');

    //I just print response using below  
    alert(response)
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

```js
// response format:
[{
  "model": "demo.state",
  "pk": 1,
  "fields": {
    "state_name": "Gujarat",
    "country": 1
  }
}, {
  "model": "demo.state",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "state_name": "Rajsthan",
    "country": 1
  }
}, {
  "model": "demo.state",
  "pk": 3,
  "fields": {
    "state_name": "Maharastra",
    "country": 1
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AJAX `success` handler you need to loop through the objects in the returned array, and pull out the `fields.state_name` property value. You can then add this to an element in the DOM any way you require. In the below example I used `append()`:

```
success: function(response) {
  response.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('#yourOutputElement').append(obj.fields.state_name);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to cycle the object, grab the items, and user the array var as you wish later, here is a small example:

```
success: function(response) {
    alert('success');

    var myAr = [];

    response.forEach(respObj => { myAr.push(respObj.fields.state_name) })
  },
```

Now you have myArr which contains all the state_name, if you provide more info on how you need them appended i can modify the answer, cheers

Answer (score 0):

in your body put this element:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

and then, your script will be:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://localhost:8000/country_state/",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
      var target=$('#result');
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var p='<p>'+data[i]['fields']['state_name']+'</p>'
        target.append(p)
      }
  }, error: function(data) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```